# Structure to run x first vs y first on 2d array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, design-patterns

I want to have a flag passed to a function that runs an algorithm by either col-scanning or row-scanning:

```
if run-on-x
  for 1..x
    for 1..y
      do something with ary[x][y]

else
  for 1..y
    for 1..x
      do something with ary[x][y]
```

But I don't want to duplicate all the loops and logic.

I've come up with this:

```
let numPx = width * height;
for (let px = 0; px < numPx; px++) {
  let [x, y] = yAxis ? [px % width, 0 | px / width] : [0 | px / height, px % height];
```

But I think all the math is rather heavy, especially when I'm running it on fairly large arrays.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If this is java, then what you are trying to do is probably a waste of time. just-in-time compilation will try to further optimize the byte-code every time the is evaluated (executed). On top of that, it is dynamic: it will change the implementation if a different branch is taken. This means it can swap the loops at run-time if it appears to be more optimal (and doesn't break any dependencies). Trying to outsmart the compiler will probably result in 'slower' code, because the optimizer will just see more potential dependencies to break.

Comment: @StarShine -- Why are you making the assumption that it's java?

Comment: No assumption. Just a comment in the case you are working in Java. To some extend, this comment also works for Javascript. The earlier browsers all did JIT-compilation of javascript, but have since moved towards native code generation. However it is likely that future evolutions of javascript compilers will have some aspects of jit such as  loop-optimzations and branch prediction optimization re-introduced when generating native byte-code as well. See also http://creativejs.com/2013/06/the-race-for-speed-part-1-the-javascript-engine-family-tree/

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps by simply passing them in as parameters like so?:

```
  function colRowScan(1stAxis,2ndAxis)
      for 1.. 1stAxis
        for 1.. 2ndAxis
          do something with ary[x][y]
```

Without seeing what the "do something" is I don't know if there is any unforeseen reasons why this couldn't work but given what you posted it should do the trick.

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do here:

```
let numPx = width * height;
for (let px = 0; px < numPx; px++) {
  let [x, y] = yAxis ? [px % width, 0 | px / width] : [0 | px / height, px % height];
```

Comment: how will you know x is in 1stAxis or 2nd axis when trying access ary[x][y]?

Comment: In both of his examples he had the format ary[x][y] so I did not change it to  confuse him but the parameters could be inserted there as well.

Comment: Can I guess this In your solution: while accessing ary[i][j] inside the loop, i will come from 1st loop and j will come from 2nd loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
function f(x, y, on_x) {
    var a, b;

    if (on_x) {
        a = x;
        b = y;
    } 
    else {
        a = y;
        b = x;
    }

    for (var ia = 0; ia < a.length; ia++) {
        for (var ib = 0; ib = b.length; ib++) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how will you know x is in a or b when trying access ary[x_i][y_j] from inside the loop? it may try to access ary[y_i][x_j] if y is in a.

Comment: @Somabrata `a[ia]` or `a[ib]` or the opposite: `b[ia]` or `b[ib]`. Alphabetical principles.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the two sets of inner and outer loops, but change the body of the inner loop to a single function call. Then there's not much code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

In your solution,

```
let numPx = width * height;
for (let px = 0; px < numPx; px++) {
  let [x, y] = yAxis ? [px % width, 0 | px / width] : [0 | px / height, px % height];
```

Number of comparison is `numPx` times while earlier it was only once, leave out the heavy math involved.

I think the simple and best solution is to use a separate function.

OR you can try this

```
var a, b, fAry;

if (run-on-x) {
    a = x;
    b = y;
    fAry = ary;
} else {
    a = y;
    b = x;
    fAry = transpose of(ary);  
}

for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < b; j++) {
        do something with fAry[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  for 1..x
    for 1..y {
      var a = run-on-x ? ary[x][y] : ary[y][x];
      do something with a
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create helper functions for row major and column major iteration, taking the array and a function to apply to the array members.

```
var rowMajor = function (a, op) {
    var maxi = a.length;
    var maxj = a[0].length;
    for(var i = 0; i < maxi; ++i) {
        var row = a[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < maxj; ++j) 
            op(row[j],i,j);
            }
};
var colMajor = function (a, op) {
    var maxi = a.length;
    if(maxi === 0) return;
    var maxj = a[0].length;
    for(var j = 0; j < maxj; ++j) {
        for(var i = 0; i < maxi; ++i) {
            op(a[i][j],i,j);
        }
    }
};

// example use (with jQuery)
var array = [[11,12,13],[21,22,23]];
var div = $('<div></div>');
var append =  function(value) { 
    div.append($('<span></span>').text(value + ' '));
};

rowMajor(array,append);
div.append('<br/>');
colMajor(array, append);
$('body').append(div);
```